# R neural network activation function

Tags: r, neural-network

I tried many packages [nnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nnet/index.html), [neuralnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/index.html) in R and other software for neural networks.

But how can I know in `nnet` or `neuralnet` which activation function is used?

And I want to have a relation ship between input and outputs, like an equation, 
`output = ...input1 (+-log..) input2`, how can I have this equation?

Comment: Check this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78252/

Comment: Thanks for stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78252

Answer (score 0):

**R** uses `Sigmoid` function by default, you can specify activation function by using `act.fct= tanh` for hyperbolic function etc. in the code.

Comment: `act.fct` is specific to then `neuralnet` package. The `nnet` package only allows toggling the output activation function between sigmoid and identity with the `linout` boolean argument where default is FALSE (therefore sigmoid).